# Добавление элемента в массив через цикл js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я создаю пустой массив и хочу в него добавить элементы через цикл, но массив получается пустым

```
var count_features = $('#count_features').val();//количество инпутов
var data = new FormData(); // мой массив
for (var i = 1; i < count_features; i++) {
    data.append("features_vip_"+i, $("#features_vip_"+i).val());
}
```

Есть ли какие то другие способы внести данные в массив через цикл?

Comment: Как ты узнал, что там пусто?

Comment: Проверил через console.log

Comment: Как именно? Ты неправильно смотришь наверняка

Comment: console.log(data); Вот скрин https://pastenow.ru/24b6859ecd18f9d59e21bc9b86a4f625

Comment: а вот я ж говорю что не правильно..... методы в форме посмотри какие есть https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries   ............. `for (let value of data.entries()) {
   console.log(value);
}`